# R graph cannot access column in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame called bigDF:

```
                         time price side PointColor shares PointSize ShapeType
231   2014-12-10 18:07:14.000    50    B      green    287        10        16
37016 2014-12-10 18:07:14.555    50           black      0         1        10
37019 2014-12-10 18:07:15.428    50           black      0         1        10
232   2014-12-10 18:07:16.000    50    B      green    713        10        16
37020 2014-12-10 18:07:17.052    50           black      0         1        10
37021 2014-12-10 18:07:17.161    50           black      0         1        10
37023 2014-12-10 18:07:17.316    50           black      0         1        10
233   2014-12-10 18:07:26.000    50    B      green    200        10        16
37024 2014-12-10 18:07:27.066    50           black      0         1        10
234   2014-12-10 18:07:28.000    50    B      green    700        10        16
37027 2014-12-10 18:07:28.346    50           black      0         1        10
235   2014-12-10 18:07:31.000    50    B      green    100        10        16
```

When I go to plot the price and highlight some points I get and error:

```
 ggplot(bigDF, aes(x=time, y=price)) + geom_line() + geom_point(   aes(shape = as.factor(ShapeType)), size=PointSize, color = PointColor)



Error in do.call("layer", list(mapping = mapping, data = data, stat = stat,  : 
  object 'PointSize' not found
```

Why is point size not found? it is in the dataframe?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

ggplot2 can only find the columns of `data` (without explicitly specifying `DF$column`) if you refer to them inside `aes`. I believe you want `geom_point(aes(shape = as.factor(ShapeType), size=PointSize, color = PointColor))`. Note the different placing of parentheses. Also note that this maps these variables to `size` and `color`. It looks like you'd also want to use `as.factor` with them and use `scale_color_manual` and `scale_size_manual`. I'd suggest to study some ggplot2 tutorials.